# Trying to Normalize my "D:" Partitation's state after replacing Windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, filesystems, partition, windows

Good Morning,
I'm trying to Normalize my "D:" Partitation's state after replacing **Windows 10** with **Ubuntu 20.10**... it shows as **Microsoft basic data** and I can't touch any Folder or File in that Partition (**/dev/sda5: Permission denied**)

For example:
When i try **sudo rmdir "DumpStack.log.tmp"**

> rmdir: failed to remove 'DumpStack.log.tmp': Read-only file system

I tried the following Method (Which didn't work):
https://askubuntu.com/a/1148959/1067284
https://askubuntu.com/a/809251/1067284

The result of **sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5** Command:

```
Mounting volume... The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sda5 was processed successfully.
```

The result of **sudo fdisk -l** Command:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 97.74 MiB, 102486016 bytes, 200168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.36 MiB, 58052608 bytes, 113384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 62.09 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 50.67 MiB, 53133312 bytes, 103776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 55.32 MiB, 58007552 bytes, 113296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 60.98 MiB, 63942656 bytes, 124888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 217.89 MiB, 228478976 bytes, 446248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 30.94 MiB, 32440320 bytes, 63360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST500LT012-9WS14
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FB9C0653-A6A2-4171-92BC-68CD5820A715

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 408274943 408035328 194.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  408274944 409597951   1323008   646M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  409600000 976773119 567173120 270.4G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/loop8: 178.98 MiB, 187674624 bytes, 366552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 169.3 MiB, 177528832 bytes, 346736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 290.44 MiB, 304545792 bytes, 594816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 125.85 MiB, 131960832 bytes, 257736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 25.53 MiB, 26771456 bytes, 52288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

- Please note that I didn't remove those Partitions(**Windows recovery environment** and **Microsoft reserved**) while Ubuntu Install-Process because I was thought that Ubuntu is going to replace it...

The result of **fdisk /dev/sda5** Command:

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda5: Permission denied
```

The result of **sudo fdisk /dev/sda5** Command:

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The device contains 'ntfs' signature and it will be removed by a write command. See fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more details.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xdbf257c4.

Command (m for help): m

Help:

  DOS (MBR)
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit nested BSD disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag

  Generic
   d   delete a partition
   F   list free unpartitioned space
   l   list known partition types
   n   add a new partition
   p   print the partition table
   t   change a partition type
   v   verify the partition table
   i   print information about a partition

  Misc
   m   print this menu
   u   change display/entry units
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

  Script
   I   load disk layout from sfdisk script file
   O   dump disk layout to sfdisk script file

  Save & Exit
   w   write table to disk and exit
   q   quit without saving changes

  Create a new label
   g   create a new empty GPT partition table
   G   create a new empty SGI (IRIX) partition table
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   s   create a new empty Sun partition table


Command (m for help): t
No partition is defined yet!
```

The result of **mount | grep sda** Command:

```
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda5 on /media/johnm/301265D312659E9A type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Please guys the only thing I want is to change it back to a normal partition with Read/Write permissions. Really I needed the data on this partition!

Comment: Your NTFS partition is mounted read only - note `ro`. I've no idea why and how you're mounting it but there's something wrong going on here. Try checking available solutions https://google.com/search?q=ubuntu+windows+partition+mounted+read+only

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I tried https://askubuntu.com/a/834298/1067284 but it didn't work

Comment: Please unmount it in your DE whatever it is and mount manually in terminal: `sudo mkdir /media/win; sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw /dev/sda5 /media/win`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov it says:                                               `Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone
A friend of mine just dropped me this awesome method which worked like charm :D

```
umount /dev/sda5
mkdir /sda5
mount /dev/sda5 /sda5
ls /sda5
```

and add the following line to **/etc/fstab** (To mount the partition after every system reboot in the /sda5 folder)
`UUID={YOUR_UUID} /sda5 ntfs-3g defaults 0 0`
please note that **{YOUR_UUID}** must be replaced with your Partition's UUID which you have got from **sudo blkid** command.

and then the Partition must be located at **/sda5** with Read/Write permissions